# execute R script using a postgresql trigger:

Tags: postgresql, trigger, scripting, r

This is my first question here, so excuse me if it does not look well organized:

I want to call a R script from a trigger (postgresql) so this script will be executed after an INSERT on my table (with a specific condition on the insert), here is what I did (based on an example that I found here):

1- I created a table to save the result

```
CREATE TABLE trigger_test (
    tt_id serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    command_output text
);
```

2- I created the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION execute_rscript()

RETURNS TRIGGER

LANGUAGE plpgsql

AS $BODY$

BEGIN

    IF NEW.idniveau = 5 THEN  

   COPY trigger_test (command_output) FROM PROGRAM 'Rscript /home/.../script.R';

END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$BODY$;
```

3- the trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_execute_rscript
    AFTER INSERT
    ON event_table
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE execute_rscript();
```

but it does not work:

> ERROR:  program "/home/.../script.R" failed DETAIL:  child process
>   exited with exit code 1 CONTEXT:  SQL statement "COPY trigger_test
>   (command_output) FROM PROGRAM '/home/.../script.R'"

any ideas please to solve this problem?

Comment: What's the first line of `script.R`? Does it start with `#!/usr/bin/R` or whatever?

Comment: just before the different libraries I put this line:                                             #!/usr/bin/Rscript

Comment: Apparently, you have to test your script, as it does not return as expected.

Comment: when I execute my script.R, it works with no problem. But when I try to execute it through the trigger it doesn't.

Comment: Possibly the environment is not set correctly for Rscript. You may want to wrap it in a shell script and capture its standard output and error for troubleshooting.

Comment: I tested my R script with a shell: #!/bin/bash
module load R/3.3.1

Rscript /home/../script.R                                                                                                          it works also with no problem when I execute the shell.                                                                                                        How can I please verify if my R environment is  (or not) correctly  set?